# Backend for react-native and web

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native

Planning to write a location-based react-native app and a web app. Need advice on the options below.

1. Should I build a backend, eg. node.js, and have both react-native and web apps talk to node.js and node.js talks to firebase?

[OR]

2. Call firebase directly from both react-native and web apps?